# How to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ using Fourier series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the value of the following series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

I don't know how to manage it. It's the third question of an exercise which I achieved the first and half of the second:

> Considering the following $f(x)=x$, $2\pi$ periodical and definend for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$
>
> 1. Determine the Fourier's trigonometrical series $S(f)$ of $f$
> 2. Give the pointwise and uniform convergence of this series.
> 3. Calculate
>    $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

I achieved **1.** and **2.** but not the uniform convergence...

from 1. $$S(f)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx)$$

Can you give me some hints?

Comment: What happens if you choose $x=\pi/2$ ?

Comment: okay, that really helps. But I'm stuck showing that $2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}\Leftrightarrow2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k+2}}{2k+1}(-1)^k=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: We have not the iff but only one direction. In fact, we have $\sin\left(n\pi/2\right)=0$ if $n$ is even, and $\sin\left(n\pi/2\right)=(-1)^p$ if $n=2p+1$ is odd. Can you see why ? Can you conclude with this ?

Comment: Okay, I think I have it:$2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+1}\sin((n+1)\frac{\pi}{2})= \frac{\pi}{2}$
$\Rightarrow 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+2}}{2k+1}\sin((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})= \frac{\pi}{2}$

But what can I say from there?

Comment: $\Rightarrow 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+2}}{2k+1}(-1)^k= \frac{\pi}{2}$?

$\Rightarrow 2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}= \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: You have $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx)=\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(2p+1)+1}}{2p+1}(-1)^{p}=\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{p}}{2p+1}$. Do not forget to justify why the Fourier series and the function $f$ coincide at $x=\pi/2$.